# Change font colour in Microsoft Chart Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, microsoft-chart-controls

How do you change the colour of the labels(not sure what the correct name is) in a [Microsoft Chart Control](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14422) in VB.

By "labels" I mean the text that is overlaid on every column in a `StackedColumn` chart.

You can change the Axis labels with the following:

```
<AxisY LineColor="Red">
      <LabelStyle ForeColor="Red" />
</AxisY>
<AxisX LineColor="Red">
       <LabelStyle ForeColor="Red" />
</AxisX>
```

What is the equivalent to target the labels?

Answer (score 0):

LabelForeColor property of Datapoint should work

```
<asp:Series Name="Default" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" ChartType="StackedColumn" >  
        <Points>
            <asp:DataPoint XValue="1" YValues="10"   LabelForeColor ="Black" Label="123" />                
        </Points>
</asp:Series>
<asp:Series Name="Default1" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" ChartType="StackedColumn" >  
        <Points>
            <asp:DataPoint XValue="1" YValues="10"   LabelForeColor ="Black" Label="123" />
       </Points>
</asp:Series>
```